# One background image for all scenes objective c

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

I have one image for background for all scenes,is it possible to write somewhere code for background so i don't have to write it on every scene I got and if it is then where I need to put it? For now i use this basic code :

```
    background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"backMenu.png"];
    titleBackground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    titleBackground.size = self.frame.size;
    titleBackground.zPosition = -10;
    [self addChild:background];
```

Comment: You could create a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`, with all of your settings, but if you want it in the scene, I think you still need to add it to the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a code which is repeated among scenes, then you can create a `BaseScene` and put that code there. So, everything shared between scenes , goes into `BaseScene`.

**BaseScene.h:**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface BaseScene : SKScene

@end
```

**BaseScene.m**

```
#import "BaseScene.h"

@interface BaseScene()

@property(nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *background;

@end

@implementation BaseScene


-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view{

    self.background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"backMenu"];
    [self addChild:self.background];

}

@end
```

**GameScene.h** (now `GameScene` inherits from `BaseScene`, not from the `SKScene`)

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "BaseScene.h"


@interface GameScene : BaseScene

@end
```

**GameScene.m**

```
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    [super didMoveToView:view];
}
@end
```

Finally, you call `[super didMoveToView:view];` in every subclass of a `BaseScene` which calls a `didMoveToView:` of a BaseScene, which in turn adds background node to the current scene.

Answer (score 0):

An `SKNode` can only belong to one scene. So you will need to add the `SKSpriteNode` for the background to every scene.

Assuming you will be creating and destroying scenes as needed what you should do is maintain a reference to the `SKTexture` for the background.

Then in that case, create the `SKSpriteNode` when needed

```
background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTex];
```

You would then add this based on your application to the scene.

In the above example, `backgroundTex` would be your reference. You should stash it in some object which maintains it. If you have a texture manager, you should be able to ask for the already allocated texture by reference name.